# Dealing with noisy movement positions

Tags: c++, opencv, position, noise

I have positions of an object moving around an image. I think I'm detecting it the best I can where most of the time I'm detecting the center of the object. However, I'm still getting the odd detection of around the center caused by the frame rate not being fast enough, and the frame containing two positions of the object.

As I can't control the frame rate, how can I minimise the effects of the noise in the jittery positions.

As this is a common issue in computer vision, are there any filters in opencv to deal with noisy position data?

Comment: yes, e.g. the [Kalman filter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#kalmanfilter)

Comment: what is your current tracking algorithm ?

Comment: Take a look also at Particle filter or condensation algorithm (it's the same, but for cv). It'll be useful in nonlinear dynamics case. The link: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~misard/condensation.html

Comment: @user3781372 We've re-opened your question, overriding the moderators close. A few of us believe it was closed out in error. Can you please re-word your question to be a little clearer? I believe you're asking what solutions might exist within openCV to solve your tracking issues. Just be more specific/clear about your request, maybe throw in some code or screenshots for good measure. :)

Comment: Good edit, +1. :) Hopefully here come some good answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Jeez... are you asking for links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked for the comment by Berak to be made into an answer, but my request was "declined". So, yes, the answer that I found most useful was to use the [Kalman filter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#kalmanfilter) which is implemented in opencv.